# Matrix that keeps the norm of the multiplied vector, but need not be square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

One key property of the unitary matrix is that it keeps the length (norm) of a vector when applied. But a unitary matrix must be square. Is there any type of matrix that doesn't need to be square, but keeps the norm constant when applied to other vectors?

Comment: Yes,, for example an identity matrix with some extra zero rows.

Comment: Oh, good example. Is there a name for such a matrix?

Comment: I'm not aware of any name for these, but the criterion is that the columns of the matrix form an *orthonormal system*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is "isometry".  It is also defined as the matrices $U$ for which $U^*U$ is the identity matrix, regardless of $UU^*$.